# HTML and Javascript picture change on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get these pictures to swap when the button is pressed, the pictures are local to my computer and need to change in sequence. When I press the button, it just generates a new picture, I need them to interchange

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var imgs=document.images;
function changeLight() {
    var firstImage = imgs[0].src + "";
    for(var i=0; i<imgs.length-1; i++){
        imgs[i].src=imgs[i+1].src+"";
    }
    imgs[imgs.length-1].src=firstImage;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="splash">
<img src="Traffic Light Red.gif" alt="" id="mainImg">

</div>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
    <img id="image" src="images/test" />
    <br><br><br>
    <button id="clickme" onclick="changeLight();">Click to change</button>


    <img src="Traffic Light Yellow.gif" hidden />
    <img src="Traffic Light Green.gif" hidden />
    <img src="Traffic Light Yellow2.gif" hidden />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `it just generates a new picture` what do you mean by this?

Comment: RIght idea, I think wrong and overengineered approach. You're doing the same thing as this link (conceptually), though onClick instead of onMouseOver...you'll need to tweak it a bit, but this should point you in the right direction: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-JavaScript-Image-Rollover

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code.  It works by comparing the `src` attributes of the hidden images, not a very elegant technique, but it works. This method will also break if you add images before the last hidden image, so use with care.

Also remember to rename the files so that they *have no spaces*. On the web, spaces get turned into %20s when being requested, which tends to break things :)

Anyways, here’s the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="splash">
             <img src="TrafficLightRed.gif" alt="" id="mainImg">
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div>
                <button id="clickme" onclick="changeLight();">Click to change</button>
                <img src="TrafficLightRed.gif" hidden>
                <img src="TrafficLightYellow.gif" hidden>
                <img src="TrafficLightGreen.gif" hidden>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            function changeLight() {
                var currentImg = document.getElementById("mainImg");
                for(var i=1;i<3;i++) {
                    if(document.images[i].src == currentImg.src) {
                        currentImg.src = document.images[i + 1].src;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                currentImg.src = document.images[1].src;
            }
         </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

A more robust technique would be to store an array of image links in your JavaScript, instead of the hacky hidden images. Brownie points for implementing that!

Answer (score 0):

so you mean first come as third, second as first and third as second??
and again the same  on next click??

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/hax3d8cv/

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#nextImage').click(function(){
            var firstImage = $('#AllImages img:first');
        $(firstImage).remove();
         $('#AllImages').append(firstImage);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

pure JavaScript. for those who says "jQuery for just this? my my" ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/0mcLcozk/

```
function f(){    
    var allImage = document.getElementById('AllImages');
    var firstImage = allImage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    allImage.removeChild(firstImage);
    allImage.appendChild(firstImage);
}
```

Comment: jQuery for just this? my my …

Comment: @RishavKundu specially for you.. check the JS version also

Answer (score 0):

Refer the script :

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>

var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 

var init = 3;
console.log(imgs[2].src);
function changeLight(){
var target = document.getElementById('imaget');

var firstImage = imgs[0].src + "";
if(init < 5 ){
target.src = imgs[init].src;
init = init +1;

}
else{
init = 3;
target.src = imgs[init].src;
}
}

</script>

</head>

<div id="splash">
<img src="Traffic Light Red.gif" alt="" id="mainImg">

</div>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
    <img id="imaget" src="images/test" />
    <br><br><br>
    <button id="clickme" onclick="changeLight();">Click to change</button>


    <img src="Traffic Light Yellow.gif" hidden />
    <img src="Traffic Light Green.gif" hidden />
    <img src="Traffic Light Yellow2.gif" hidden />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This works for me. I would like to suggest you to use `array values` (image srcs)  set in javascript instead of using hidden images.

Comment: Uhh, why do you have two opening tags for body?